# If two models generate identical predictions, must one be mathematically reducible to the other?

Tags: mathematics, observables, models

If two models always generate identical predictions of measurable observables given identical inputs of measurements over a given domain, must one be mathematically reducible to the other over that domain? I'm pretty sure the answer would be yes - *identically mapping if and only if identical map*, but I'm not 100% confident and I don't think I could rigorously defend my conclusion. I'd appreciate any insights.

---

To improve clarity: A measurement is identical if both the value and the measurement error are identical. A prediction is identical if the statistical distribution of predictions are identical; if we run the experiment a million times from identically measured initial conditions, both models should predict the same distribution of measured end conditions.

This question concerns only the initial conditions and the predictions, not actual measurements of the end conditions, which may or may not comport with the predictions.

For example, suppose it is eventually shown that String Theory works as a successful theory of quantum gravity. Suppose further that if we set to zero whatever String Theory uses to represent the gravitation of everything in the universe except for a few fundamental particles having interactions, String Theory makes predictions identical to those made by the Standard Model. Does this necessarily imply that String Theory under the condition of no external gravitation is mathematically identical to the Standard Model, however radically different it appears?

Put another way, is proving that they make identical predictions and proving that they are mathematically identical under this condition the same mathematical task?

Comment: It would depend on the accuracy of measuring the predictions. If the measurement errors are large enough?

Comment: I have a model that predicts the number of days it will rain next month is equal to the number of planets in the solar system.   I have another that predicts the number of days it will rain next month is equal to the number of non-thumb fingers on my hands.   These aren't very useful models, but they do make predictions of measurable observables, and the predictions are identical.   Do you consider them "mathematically reducible" to each other?

Comment: @WillO if you have to strip the units before inputting, then they appear to be trivially identical (and they're just an operator, "multiply the input by days of rain"). If you don't have to strip the units before inputting, they don't take the same inputs, because fingers are not planets, so they can't be the same.

Comment: @annav by identical I mean including identical error bars.

Comment: @gs    the error bars come from the measurements, so they should be identical as far as the theoretical calculations . I am saying if they are large enough any theoretical value can fit.

Answer (score 3):

In general, here is the way these things work:

If two different models yield exactly the same result over their entire range of applicability it suggests that they are just different *mathematical formalisms* (for example, Heisenberg versus Schrodinger), ripe for some young genius (i.e., Dirac) to unravel and show their equivalence. This of course depends on if they call forth the same starting conditions, in the form of foundational principles, symmetries, conservation laws and so on. The practitioner is then free to pick which formalism solves the problem at hand with the least amount of work.

It is more common for one model to make wrong predictions at the extremes of its applicability range while another model gets it right in those regimes. In this case the model that fails is often a still-useful *low-energy approximation* to the truth expressed in the second model.

Comment: Do you consider Bohm's formulation if QM a different version of formalism than standard formulation?

Comment: @ValterMoretti, I do not know enough about it to comment. -NN